# Method of lines - Dirichlet and mixed BC

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, finite-element-method, chemistry, finite-difference-method

I have a dissolution problem to solve with two equations (everything is in dimensionless form - concentration, time and distance - EDIT: that came from the second Fick's law, where the distance was normalized by L, time by L^2/D_H and S by S_h^0) :

[image]

that represents diffusion equation for proton transport across the fluid boundary layer in dimensionless form;

and [image]

that represents the transport equation for the porous layer.

There are three layers (rock, porous media and liquid media), three boundary conditions, and one initial condition:
[image]

My main challenge is to solve all the equations simultaneously to obtain the rate:

[image].

EDIT: where J_H is the first Fick law, Bi is the Biot number

In summary, that is the representation of my problem

[image]

and this is what I'm trying to obtain: Dissolution rate as a function of layer thickness for different values of ε; and Dissolution rate as a function of layer thickness for different Biot numbers (Bim).

[image]  and [image]

EDIT: Im tryng to reproduce those results: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0009254122001620?via%3Dihub

Here is my code, but unfortunately it is not working.

EDIT: I change my code but is still not working

```
(* Problem parameters *)
epsilon = 0.1;
Bi = 2.0;
lValues = Range[0, 10, 1];  (* Different values of l for the R plot *)

(* Discretization of space and time *)
Nx = 100;  (* Number of points in x *)
Nt = 200;  (* Number of points in time *)
dx = 1.0/Nx;
dt = 1.0/Nt;

(* Matrix initialization *)
SH = ConstantArray[0, {Nx, Nt + 1}];

(* Initial condition *)
SH[[All, 1]] = ConstantArray[0, Nx];

(* Main loop - Finite difference method *)
For[n = 1, n <= Nt, n++,
  For[i = 2, i <= Nx - 1, i++,
    SH[[i, n + 1]] = SH[[i, n]] + 
      dt*((SH[[i + 1, n]] - 2 SH[[i, n]] + SH[[i - 1, n]])/(dx^2) - 
        epsilon*(SH[[i + 1, n]] - SH[[i - 1, n]])/(2*dx)
    )
  ];

  (* Central boundary condition *)
  SH[[1, n + 1]] = 1;

  (* Boundary condition at the end *)
  SH[[-1, n + 1]] = Bi*SH[[-1, n]]*dx + SH[[-2, n + 1]];
];

(* Plotting the SH graph over x *)
xValues = Range[0, 1, dx];
ListLinePlot[SH[[All, -1]], DataRange -> {0, 1}, PlotLabel -> "Distribution of SH along x", 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "SH"}, ImageSize -> Medium]

(* Calculating R for different l values *)
RValues = Table[Bi*SH[[Round[l*Nx], -1]], {l, lValues}];

(* Plotting the R graph over l *)
ListPlot[Transpose[{lValues, RValues}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium], 
  PlotLabel -> "R values for different l values", 
  AxesLabel -> {"l", "R"}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

Comment: 1. Please double check those formulas, for example, some $S_H$ is mistakenly written as $S_h$ in your picture. 2. Why do you write a difference formula in https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0QOC.png and claim it's a boundary condition? What does it mean? 3. What's $J_H$? 4. Why not directly use `NDSolve`?

Comment: 1) Please also present your equations as Mathematica code. 2) Have you tried `NDSolve` rather than writing your own solver?

Comment: I can't use NDSolve.. I really need to write my own code

Comment: In what sense does your code not work?  Errpr messages?  Clearly wrong answers?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve this problem using FDM and `NDSolve` as well to compare solutions. First code with FDM implementation

```
R[L_, Bi_, \[CurlyEpsilon]_] := 
  Module[{SpatialStep = 0.1, TemporalStep = 0.001, FinalTime = 1.0}, 
   nTemporalSteps = Round[FinalTime/TemporalStep]; 
   grid1 = Range[0, 1, SpatialStep]; nx1 = Length[grid1]; 
   grid2 = Range[1, L + 1, SpatialStep]; nx2 = Length[grid2];
   
   (*Initialize the grid*)
   SH0[x_] := Exp[-(x)^2]; (*Initial condition for SH*)
   Sh0[x_] := 
    Exp[-1]*(1 - 
       1/Pi Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - 1)/L]); (*Initial condition for Sh*)
   
   (*Lists to store the results*)
   solutionSH = Table[0, {nx1}, {nTemporalSteps}];
   solutionSh = Table[0, {nx2}, {nTemporalSteps}];
   
   (*Initial conditions*)
   solutionSH[[All, 1]] = SH0[#] & /@ grid1;
   solutionSh[[All, 1]] = Sh0[#] & /@ grid2; 
   M21 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], grid1, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; 
   M22 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], grid2, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 2]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   
   (*Solve the equations*)
   For[n = 1, n < nTemporalSteps, n++, 
    solutionSH[[2 ;; -2, n + 1]] = 
     solutionSH[[2 ;; -2, n]] + 
      TemporalStep (M21 . solutionSH[[All, n]])[[2 ;; -2]];
    (*Dirichlet boundary condition at x=0*)
    solutionSH[[1, n + 1]] = 1;
    
    solutionSh[[All, n + 1]] = 
     solutionSh[[All, n]] + 
      TemporalStep \[CurlyEpsilon] M22 . solutionSh[[All, n]];
    (*Boundary conditions at x=1*)
    solutionSH[[-1, n + 1]] = 
     solutionSH[[-2, 
       n + 1]] + \[CurlyEpsilon] (solutionSh[[2, n + 1]] - 
         solutionSh[[1, n + 1]]);
    solutionSh[[1, n + 1]] = solutionSH[[-1, n + 1]];
    (*Mixed boundary condition at x=l+1*)
    solutionSh[[-1, 
      n + 1]] = (solutionSh[[-2, n + 1]])/(1 + 
        Bi /\[CurlyEpsilon] SpatialStep );]; 
   Bi solutionSh[[-1, -1]]];
```

Visualization $R_{AB}(\epsilon)$

```
RAB = Table[
   Table[{L, R[L, 1, eps]}, {L, 1, 10, .1}], {eps, {.5, .1, .01}}];
p1 = ListLinePlot[RAB, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"\[CurlyEpsilon] =", eps}], {eps, {0.5, .1, .01}}], 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> Row[{"Bi =", 1}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Layer thickness, L", 
    "Dissolution rate, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(AB\)]\)"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Red, Dashed}, {Green, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Figure 1]
Note, that for initial condition used above the time integration `FinalTime = 1.` is too small. It is why we see waves in the plot `p1`.
Second code

```
d[x_, e_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 <= x < 1}, {e, True}}]; 
ini[x_, L_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Exp[-x], 
    0 <= x < 1}, {Exp[-1]*(1 - 1/Pi Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - 1)/L]), True}}]; 
R1[L_, Bi_, eps_] := 
 Module[{}, 
  sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] - D[d[x, eps] D[u[t, x], x], x] ==
       NeumannValue[-Bi u[t, x], x == L + 1], 
     DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 1, x == 0], u[0, x] == ini[x, L]}, 
    u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, L + 1}]; sol];
```

Visualization $R_{AB}(\epsilon)$

```
p2 = ListLinePlot[
  Table[Table[{L, R1[L, 1, eps][1, L + 1]}, {L, 1, 
     10, .1}], {eps, {0.5, .1, .01}}], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Table[Row[{"\[CurlyEpsilon] =", eps}], {eps, {0.5, .1, .01}}], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 2]
Now we can compare two solutions

```
Show[p1,p2]
```

[image: Figure 2]
We can see a slight difference due to errors of $h^2$ (`h=SpatialStep`) in the FDM solution. Finally we can reproduce Figure 2,a from the [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0009254122001620?via%3Dihub) as follows

```
list10 = 
  Table[Table[{L, R1[L, 1, eps][10, L + 1]}, {L, .01, 
     10, .1}], {eps, {0.5, .1, .01}}];

ListLinePlot[list10, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Table[Row[{"\[CurlyEpsilon] =", eps}], {eps, {0.5, .1, .01}}], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Layer thickness, L", 
   "Dissolution rate, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(AB\)]\)"}]
```

[image: Figure 4]